# Add url as parameter for query using Tesseract OCR

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using `tesseract` ocr  and it is working perfectly. But my question is can I run tesseract with a url as parameter.

I am looking to do the following

```
localhost/test.html/?othersite.com/image/image2.jpg
```

Some Image url for demo:

```
 1. https://i.imgur.com/leBXjxq.png
 2. https://i.imgur.com/7u9LyF6.png
```

when the results are processed it would then come to a `text-area` box.

Here's a code :

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Tesseract-JS Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Image URL" />

     <!--<div id="ocr_results"> </div>-->
     <div id="ocr_status"> </div>
     <div>
        <label>Filed1
        <label>
           <textarea id="txt" ></textarea>
     </div>


  </body>

 <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js
 /1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
  <script 

  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/
  libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function runOCR(url) {
  Tesseract.recognize(url)
  .then(function(result) {
  document.getElementById("txt")
  .innerHTML = result.text;
  document.getElementById('txt').focus();

  }).progress(function(result) {
  document.getElementById("ocr_status")
  .innerText = result["status"] + " (" +
  (result["progress"] * 100) + "%)";
  });
  }
  document.getElementById("url")
  .addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  runOCR(url);

  });


 </script>
```

Comment: hi @nur-islam can you share some more details on the code that you are attempting to run. It will help other users to provide an answer for you. Very interesting question by the way. I have only used tesseract in C#. how are you actually executing tesseract?

Comment: Also instead of sharing the code in the link please share in the post.

Comment: i just update code link, now run perfectly, I put some image url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `localhost/test.html?image=https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrOsS.png`

And you can get the image from the URL in JavaScript like so:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myImage = urlParams.get('image');
```

**myImage** variable will be: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrOsS.png" and then you can pass it to your OCR method.

A sample code will be:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myImage = urlParams.get('image');
if (myImage) {
    runOCR(myImage);
}
```

Here is a link with updated code: https://gist.github.com/kolarski/0bc2a3feb02adb1b63016d0d78b3653c

Comment: But Its not working. Can u pls elaborate with my code?

Comment: I have updated with sample code. But keep in mind that this will not work in the js.do online editor, because it does not support such query parameters. It will not pass them to your JS code. You will need to run it standalone.

Comment: What if ! When I open other site then automatically copy  image id's src(by using getElementById) than pass src  to my server and return result and save result my to server.

Comment: base64 image not woking